# Change the variable if there is an int input

Tags: godot, gdscript

My objective is, if I type "points" it will show me the content of the variable but if I add an int after it, it will change the value of the variable

This is what I have right now:

```
func add_message(text):
    chatLog.bbcode_text += '\n'
    chatLog.bbcode_text += text

func text_entered(text):
    if text == "points":
        chatLog.bbcode_text = ''
        add_message("Current value of [color=yellow]Points: [/color]" + str("[color=fuchsia]" + str(points) + "[/color]"))
        inputField.text = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input text and split it into words with `split`. Then take them one by one:

```
func text_entered(text):
    var tokens = text.split(" ")
    var count = tokens.size()
    if count == 0:
        # (empty input)
        return # or whatever

    if count > 0 and tokens[0] == "points":
        if count > 1 and tokens[1].is_valid_integer():
            # points int
            var integer = tokens[1].to_int()
            points = points + integer # or whatever
        elif count > 1:
            # points invalid_int
            pass # or whatever
        else:
            # points
            pass # or whatever
    else:
        pass # not_points
```

In the above code we are using `is_valid_integer` to verify that the current word is an integer, and if so we can convert it with `to_int`.